# ScintillaNET autocomplete

Tags: c#, scintilla

Where i should insert my list of autocomplete in ScintillaNet.

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();

s.Add("include();");
s.Add("test");
s.Add("test2");

s.Sort();

scintilla1.AutoComplete.List = s;
scintilla1.AutoComplete.Show();
```

I have tried to insert this in function to set options but it doesen't work. If I paste this text to function scintilla1_CharAdded(), pop-up was open always, and was very dificult to write something.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `AutoCShow` with the word list as second argument like this:

```
scintilla1.AutoCShow(lengthEntered, s);
```

Where `lengthEntered` is an integer of the entered characters and `s` your list of words.